# Paypal url is displaying funny looking character

Tags: html, paypal

I have a payPal url and it has `&currency_code=CAD` in the url when it is displayed on the site says `¤cy_code=CAD` why is it doing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Just saying: ¤ - &curren; Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: on my site its displaying ¤cy_code=CAD, its replacing the &curren with ¤

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a thought, `&curren;` is the HTML code for `¤`. If you are displaying the URL than contains that code on the webpage itself, then it will show up as `¤`. You can use `&amp;curren` to properly display the url.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to encode the url before you display it:

```
url_encode($url)
```